# searchCriteria returning every result

Tags: magento2.2

I'm currently using PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod to access Magento APIs.  My problem is I'm trying to pass some searchCriteria in a $body variable to look for a specific 'increment_id'.
Here is the code:

```
    $body = @{
'searchCriteria' = @{
         'filterGroups' = @{
                 'filters' = @{
                         'field' = 'increment_id'
                         'value' = '878'
                         'condition_type' = 'eq'
                     }
                }
            }
        }

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $header -Body $body -OutFile "C:\order.txt"
```

When this command is run, I get a response that contains all of the orders on our site.  At this point, I'm just trying to learn my way through using the Invoke-RestMethod command, but my end goal is to use this command to retrieve the latest order that was placed on the Magento site.

Thanks,
Trevor

Comment: please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314994/get-the-value-of-sales-order-address-table-custom-column-value-in-rest-v1-orders?noredirect=1#comment452389_314994 if you need a solution